# Switch images with addEventListener in JavaScript without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to switch images with addEventListner. I can do it with arrays, but trying to test with event listener, but having problems with it.

HTML:

```
<img id="previous" style="left: 0">&lt;</img>
<img id="mainImg" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499825595/DSC_0015_b0hr2j.jpg"></img>
<img id="next" style="right: 0">&gt;</img>
```

JavaScript:

```
const slider = [
    {
       imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg",
   },
   {
       imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826238/DSC_0360_sfwyqh.jpg",

   },
   {
       imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826221/DSC_0303_esrlla.jpg",
   },
];

 var i = 0;

 var sliderImg = document.querySelector("mainImg");
 sliderImg.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       e.src = e[i+1].imgSrc;
       ++i;
 });
```

Comment: `but having problems with it` What does it mean ?

Comment: Switching the image.

Comment: Replace `e.src` with `e.target.src`

Comment: By the way, you have inverted the brackets and the curly brackets for your `slider` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event of a click event is not the object itself, but an `Event` object. You'll need to access the `target` property to set `src`.

```js
e.target.src
```

Also, you're trying to use array syntax on the Event rather than on the Array itself. `e[i+1].imgSrc` isn't really anything. There's a few strategies you can take to properly cycle through the array of images. One would be to keep track of the current index of your image in the array and increment it with each click. I think that's the direction you were headed based on the `i` variable.

**Note:** be careful of scoping inside a click event handler. `this` scope has changed unless you're in a situation where you can use arrow functions.

```js
// Your array is overly complex
const slider = [
  { imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" },
  { imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826238/DSC_0360_sfwyqh.jpg" },
  { imgSrc: "https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826221/DSC_0303_esrlla.jpg" },
];

 var sliderImg = document.querySelector("mainImg");
 sliderImg.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       i++;
       // test if you've exceeded the array limits and loop back to 0.
       if (i === slider.length) {
            i = 0;
       }       
               // use slider here
       e.target.src = slider[i].imgSrc;

 });
```

Comment: IIRC, in a DOM listener "non-arrow" callback `this` references the actual DOM element so you could replace `e.target.src` with `this.src`.

Comment: I made a few edit-tweaks to the code there. I'm answering this blind in the browser and there were a number of little things to clean up. I still see some additional ones at a glance, but I'm headed out. `querySelector` will need a "#mainImg" not just mainImg. You could use getElementById instead without the # if you want. Anyway, this should get you close enough to clean up the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your `const slider` was not good syntax, it's an array which contain object not the invert, you can directly access the `src` of your `img` with `this` keyword :

```js
const slider = [
    {
        imgSrc: "https://www.andlil.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/R%C3%A8gle-1.png",
    },
    {
        imgSrc: "http://mooc.politechnicart.net/newageofhumanity/wp-content/uploads/sites/34/number-2-design-md.png",
    },
    {
        imgSrc: "http://ruedesoptions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/chiffre3.jpg",
    },
];
let i = 0;

let sliderImg = document.querySelector("#mainImg");
sliderImg.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (i < (slider.length - 1)) {
        this.src = slider[++i].imgSrc;
        document.querySelector('#text-img').innerText = "image " + i.toString() + " src : " + slider[i].imgSrc
    }
});

let prevImg = document.querySelector("#previous");
prevImg.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (i > 0) {
        sliderImg.src = slider[--i].imgSrc;
        document.querySelector('#text-img').innerText = "image " + i.toString() + " src : " + slider[i].imgSrc
    }
});
let nextImg = document.querySelector("#next");
nextImg.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (i < (slider.length - 1)) {
        sliderImg.src = slider[++i].imgSrc;
        document.querySelector('#text-img').innerText = "image " + i.toString() + " src : " + slider[i].imgSrc
    }
});
```

```css
 img {
      max-height: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<button id="previous" style="left: 0">&lt;</button>
<img style="max-height: 50px;" id="mainImg" src="https://www.andlil.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/R%C3%A8gle-1.png"></img>
<button id="next" style="right: 0">&gt;</button>
<p id="text-img"></p>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Same as I am having problem that it doesn't bring the next image.

Comment: I've updated the snippet to change image url and show the path of current image

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `e.src` might not be what you want to access.

```
 sliderImg.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       e.src = e[i+1].imgSrc;
       ++i;
 });
```

`e` actually returns the `event`.

```
const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');

img1.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.src = 'http://placekitten.com/g/300/200'
});
```